# RMI theory - Stub and Distributed Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi

I have two answers about RMI theory.

1) Let's take a look to :

```
Service impl = new Service();
```

Supposing that Service is the implementation of a remote interface and that it extends UniCastRemoteObject;

If (server side) I create impl with the code above and then call:

```
impl.f();
```

To execute f() , JVM uses stub? In other words f() will be called as remote method ?

2) I was looking for Distributed Garbage collection , I have implemented unreference method to see when the counter associated to a remote object becomes zero, it works fine.
I have implemented also finalize method, but this is never called, can you explain why?
I have tried also to unbind the remote reference UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(impl,true); but finalize doesn't get called.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2):

> To execute f() , JVM uses stub? In other words f() will be called as remote method ?

No. But if you executed it via the stub at the server, it would go via RMI. No short-circuiting.

> I have implemented also finalize method, but this is never called, can you explain why?

Because the object isn't being garbage-collected locally. You may have another reference to it other that via an RMI client. DGC releases *RMI's* references to the object, but it doesn't release your own. *All* references must be released for local GC to occur, and even them there is no guarantee it will ever happen.

Answer (score 1):

1) No, when you talk locally to the remote object, this won't go via stub. A stub is generally only inserted if you retrieve the object from the RMI registry, or if you get the reference in another remote call.

2) I don't know too much about the algorithm that's used, but RMI does have distributed garbage collection and should take care of freeing unused objects. But just as with any garbage collection, if the reference count goes to zero, that doesn't mean that the object will automatically be garbage collected. That generally only happens when the system needs to free memory, and that may never be the case during the lifetime of your application.

Comment: Then, It can be that RMIregistry holds a reference to the remote object and so GC can not  deallocate memory?

Comment: The RMI registry will only contain references to objects that you put into it explicitly. Objects are never inserted implicitly.

Comment: When I call Naming.rebind() I put into it explicitly

Comment: @Edge7 If the RMI Registry is holding a reference, the DGC reference count can't be zero.